# Send file from php server to Android client

Tags: java, php, android, file

I try to send file from php server to Andorid client. This is my java code:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));

in = response.getEntity().getContent();
 } 
  catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception");
  }


  String fileName = "form.xml";
  File destinationfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ServiceHelper/" + fileName);


BufferedOutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationfile));
byte byt[] = new byte[1024];
int i;

for (long l = 0L; (i = in.read(byt)) != -1; l += i ) {
    buffer.write(byt, 0, i);
}
```

I have no idea how it should look like part of the server in php, to send and save a file, for example, tx, or xml.

I will be very grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Simplified example add try catch in the correct places etc.

```
String fileName = "form.xml";
URL url = new URL( "http://example.com/form.php" );
File destinationfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ServiceHelper/" + fileName);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
input = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n = - 1;
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( file );
while ( (n = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
output.close();

//Refresh file location MediaScannerConnection
if (destinationfile != null) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { destinationfile.toString() }, null, null);
}
```

**In PHP from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp):**

`form.php`

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<note>";
echo "<from>Jani</from>";
echo "<to>Tove</to>";
echo "<message>Remember me this weekend</message>";
echo "</note>";
?>
```